# How can I remove elements from an array with a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, checkbox, react-hooks

I am learning React and I was trying to make a project where there are some random question cards. I wanted to add a configuration option where before playing you can choose which questions to play with.

Here is what I tried with one of the cards

App.js:

```
const [checkedOrange1, setCheckedOrange1] = useState(false)
const handleChangeOrange1 = () => {
  setCheckedOrange1(!checkedOrange1)
}
const [checkedOrange2, setCheckedOrange2] = useState(false)
const handleChangeOrange2 = () => {
  setCheckedOrange2(!checkedOrange2)
}
const [checkedOrange3, setCheckedOrange3] = useState(false)
const handleChangeOrange3 = () => {
  setCheckedOrange3(!checkedOrange3)
}
const [checkedOrange4, setCheckedOrange4] = useState(false)
const handleChangeOrange4 = () => {
  setCheckedOrange4(!checkedOrange4)
}
const [checkedOrange5, setCheckedOrange5] = useState(false)
const handleChangeOrange5 = () => {
  setCheckedOrange5(!checkedOrange5)
}
const [checkedOrange6, setCheckedOrange6] = useState(false)
const handleChangeOrange6 = () => {
  setCheckedOrange6(!checkedOrange6)
}


Question 1
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeOrange1} />
Question 2
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeOrange2} />
Question 3
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeOrange3} />
Question 4
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeOrange4} />
Question 5
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeOrange5} />
Question 6
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeOrange6} />
```

And this is the code of the component of the question card

```
let Arrayorange = [  {
      question: "Question 1",
      id: 1
  },
  {
      question: "Question 2",
      id: 2
  },
  {
      question: "Question 3",
      id: 3
  },
  {
    question: "Question 4",
    id: 4
},
  {
      question: "Question 5",
      id: 5
  },
  {
      question: "Question 6",
      id: 6
  }
];

const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState(Arrayorange);
const [randomCard, setRandomCard] = React.useState({condicion:'start'});

    if(stateorange1 === true){
      let idorange1 = 1;
      let index = question.findIndex(item => item.id === idorange1);
      question.splice(index, 1)
    }
    if(stateorange2 === true){
      let idorange2 = 2;
      let index = question.findIndex(item2 => item2.id === idorange2);
      question.splice(index, 1)
    }
    if(stateorange3 === true){
      let idorange3 = 3;
      let index = question.findIndex(item3 => item3.id === idorange3);
      question.splice(index, 1)
    }
    if(stateorange4 === true){
      let idorange4 = 4;
      let index = question.findIndex(item4 => item4.id === idorange4);
      question.splice(index, 1)
    }
    if(stateorange5 === true){
      let idorange5 = 5;
      let index = question.findIndex(item5 => item5.id === idorange5);
      question.splice(index, 1)
    }
    if(stateorange6 === true){
      let idorange6 = 6;
      let index = question.findIndex(item6 => item6.id=== idorange6);
      question.splice(index, 1)
    }
```

The main problem is that it deletes more than I need. If I mark 5 I run out of cards, if I mark 1 I am left with only 1 instead of 5 and so on. Thank you very much in advance for your answers

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-problem-ovp74y

Comment: Hello :) Do you have any minimal example of your issue? Like codesandbox?

Comment: first of all, using one var for every card is really bad practice, try using an array and it will maybe solve your problem

Comment: Yes, here's a demo of it https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-problem-ovp74y

Comment: How would it be to use an Array?